# Converting Oracle Database Types to Postgres / Hibernate Mapping

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, annotations, pojo

Currently i am migrating my legacy application from Oracle to Postgres.
Within my POJOs i am having issues with following new datatypes.

| Datatype in Oracle | New Datatype in Postgres | Data Type in Spring Boot (Hibernate Entity) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NUMBER(X,0) | NUMERIC(X,0) | String |
| SMALLINT | NUMERIC(1,0) | boolean |

How can i map this within my Hibernate Entity correctly?
Currently i am getting always Type Exceptions because of character does not match numeric etc.

For the boolean is somehow fixed it by adding @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType)
but there i have also to change the Java Type from boolean to Boolean which i would like to avoid

My current research should i need to write an own UserType for it, but somehow i am bit confused because i don't think Numeric to String / boolean is such a rare case so that nobody included already a Logic / UserType within Hibernate.

Comment: A `numeric` type should be mapped to a BigDecimal. **Never** store numbers in strings. But a `number(x,0)` from Oracle is probably better mapped to an `integer` or `bigint` in Postgres (depends on the value of X). A `smallint` in Oracle and it should be mapped to a `smallint` in Postgres. Or better a `boolean` if that stores a boolean flag.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. for the `smallint` i am actually thinking about to convert it into a `boolean` (probably align it with data migration then). For the `number` i am also unhappy that this was initially used and not as a `varchar`. Is there anyway out-of-the-box way to still tell hibernate that it should be treated as a String, but the database Type still remains `numeric`?

Comment: Why would you want to handle numbers as Strings inside your Java application? That makes zero sense to me.

Comment: Note that Oracle doesn't really have a `smallint` data type. It's converted to `number` internally which will allow to store values as high as `1e100` so you might want to make sure that the column really only contains `0` and `1`

Comment: i think the former developer handled it as a String because functionally the number is more like a label. e.g a telephone number or a description based on numbers.  Therefore i think it was easier initially to map it to a string to use it within the application. For Oracle this wasn't a problem but with Postgres now this a bit differently

Comment: If it's not really a number, then it should be a `varchar` (or `text`) in the database.